# How to Insert data with sequence value in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I Have a table like as below:

```
StudentName,  StudentNo,  SchoolCode etc.,
-----------  ---------- ----------
```

While inserting data i have to generate a sequence number based on `SchoolCode` .

For Eg: SchoolCode:1 sequence num: 1,2,3,... and for SchoolCode:2 again it should start from 1,2,3..

How to do this?

Comment: Specify with an example please.

Answer (score 0):

You can Identity Column ON `school code`

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
ADD SCHOOL_CODE INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

If You want To Generate Like this `'AA-01','AA-02'`
then something like this :

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Student
(
    StudentId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     School_Code AS 'AA-' + CAST(StudentId as varchar(16)) 
)
```

[MSDN SOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188059.aspx)

Comment: Grats. BASED ON - smells like "ALA-001, ALA-002" for me. At best the question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. Identity column generates sequence number for every record.But, i need sequence number based on school code. For Eg: SchoolCode:1 sequence num: 1,2,3,... and for SchoolCode:2 again it should start from 1,2,3..